# What's the best way to find unique unhashable unorderable types in Python 3

Tags: python, python-3.x

So in Python 2 you could use something like

```
>>> items = [[1, 2], [3], [3], 4, 'a', 'b', 'a']
>>> from itertools import groupby
>>> [k for k, g in groupby(sorted(items))]
[4, [1, 2], [3], 'a', 'b']
```

Which works well, in `O(N log N)` time. However Python 3 exclaims `TypeError: unorderable types: int() < list()`. So What's the best way to do it in Python 3? (I know best is a subjective term but really there should be one way of doing it according to Python)

EDIT: It doesn't have to use a sort, but I'm guessing that would be the best way

Comment: Can those lists not be tuples?

Comment: @JakobBowyer Forgive me for not thinking up a better example, for the sake of this question and it's title, let's say they can't

Comment: @JakobBowyer: That wouldn't help anything; then he'd just get an error about `int` and `tuple` being unorderable.

Comment: @user2282357: Why are you adding the `groupby` complexity here? The error comes in `sorted(items)`; you don't need any more than that.

Comment: @abarnert I don't quite follow. that was just a way to get unique elements

Comment: @user2282357: If you could do Python 2-style sorting here, you'd be done, right?

Comment: @abarnert That would be one possible solution. I can't think of anything better but I'm not sure

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In 2.x, values of two incomparable built-in types are ordered by type. The order of the types is not defined, except that it will be consistent during one run of the interpreter. So, `2 < [2]` may be true or false, but it will be *consistently* true or false.

In 3.x, values of incomparable built-in types are incomparable—meaning they raise a `TypeError` if you try to compare them. So, `2 < [2]` is an error. And, at least as of 3.3, the types themselves aren't even comparable. But if all you want to reproduce is the 2.x behavior, their `id`s are definitely comparable, and consistent during a run of the interpreter. So:

```
sorted(items, key=lambda x: (id(type(x)), x))
```

For your use case, that's all you need.

---

However, this won't be exactly the same thing that 2.x does, because it means that, for example, `1.5 < 2` may be `False` (because `float` > `int`). If you want to duplicate the exact behavior, you need to write a key function that first tries to compare the values, then on `TypeError` falls back to comparing the types.

This is one of the few cases where an old-style `cmp` function is a lot easier to read than a new-style `key` function, so let's write one of those, then use [`cmp_to_key`](http://docs.python.org/3.3/library/functools.html#functools.cmp_to_key) on it:

```
def cmp2x(a, b):
    try:
        if a==b: return 0
        elif a<b: return -1
        elif b<a: return 1
    except TypeError:
        pass
    return cmp2x(id(type(a)), id(type(b)))
sorted(items, key=functools.cmp_to_key(cmp2x))
```

This still doesn't guarantee the same order between two values of different types that 2.x would give, but since 2.x didn't define any such order (just that it's consistent within one run), there's no way it could.

There is still one real flaw, however: If you define a class whose objects are not fully-ordered, they will end up sorting as equal, and I'm not sure this is the same thing 2.x would do in that case.

Comment: I'm no python expert yet, but, aren't the dictionaries supposed to solve this kind of problems ? `{"key":value, ...}`

Comment: @user2244984: I'm not sure how dictionaries would solve anything related to the original problem. Sets would… but the whole problem is that the values aren't hashable, which means they can't be used with either sets or dictionaries.

Comment: ok, I need a definition for **unhashable** because this is the first the time that I read about this term: what's _not_ hashable ?

Comment: @abarnert Your first example gives me: `TypeError: unorderable types: type() < type()`, the second one seems to work, the sorting isn't the same as Python 2 if you try it with `3.3` and `4.4` in the list but that wasn't my question so I guess that's fine.

Comment: Technically, any object that either doesn't define `__hash__`, or whose `__hash__` raises a `TypeError`, is not hashable. (Really, if it raises any other kind of error, it's still not hashable.)

Comment: @user2282357: Oops, at some point they made types non-orderable as well. Since no two types are equal, there are no implied transitivity relations, and the order of types was never defined (except that it was consistent within one run of the program), you can just use `hash(type())`… let me edit the answer to explain that.

Comment: @TokenMacGuy: I already put `id` in the answer, and explained it, at least 10 minutes ago (right after typing that comment).

Comment: Ok the first solution works fine, thanks, I doubt it can get better than that unless Python makes a builtin `uniquify`

Comment: @user2282357: Well, `set` pretty much _is_ the builtin `uniquify`. But unfortunately, it only works for hashable values.

Answer (score 2):

Let's take a step back.

You want to uniquify a collection.

If the values were hashable, you'd use the O(N) `set` solution. But they're not. If you could come up with some kind of hash function, you could equivalently use a `dict` of `myhash(value): value`. If your use case really is "nothing but hashable values and flat `list`s of hashable values", you could do that by `try`ing to `hash`, then falling back to `hash(tuple())`. But in general, that's not going to work.

If they were fully ordered, you'd use the O(N log N) `sorted` solution (or, equivalent, a tree-based solution or similar). If you could come up with some kind of full-ordering function, you could just pass a `key` to the `sorted` function. I think this will work in your use case (hence my other answer). But, if not, no O(N log N) solution is going to work.

If they're neither, you can fall back to the O(N**2) linear search solution:

```
unique = []
for value in items:
    if value not in unique:
        unique.append(value)
```

If you can't find some way to define a full-ordering or a hash function on your values, this is the best you can do.